# How to load large numpy file without memory dump into kaggle notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning

I am working with a [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/histopathologic-cancer-detection/data) to train a Keras Deep Learning model on a Kaggle notebook with a GPU. The dataset has a csv which contains an id, for a `.tif` image in another directory, and a label, 1 or 0. I balanced the data and saved it using `numpy.save()` (See Code 1). This works fine and afterwards, I download the files and reupload them as a dataset. However, when I try to use this dataset in a different notebook using `numpy.load()` (See Code 2), I get the following error:

```
Your notebook tried to allocate more memory than is available. It has restarted.
```

I have been following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j-3vuBynnOE), and it's a few years old, so I might be doing unnecessary steps while making the array. How do I fix the memory dump issue?

I have already tried using pickle to save the array produced by Code 1, but it has the same memory dump error.

Code 1:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2
import random

df = pd.read_csv("../input/histopathologic-cancer-detection/train_labels.csv")

ones_subset = df.loc[df["label"] == 1, :]
num_ones = len(ones_subset)

zeros_subset = df.loc[df["label"] == 0, :]
sampled_zeros = zeros_subset.sample(num_ones)

print(num_ones)
print(sampled_zeros)

df = pd.concat([ones_subset, sampled_zeros], ignore_index=True)
df = df.groupby("label").sample(50000).sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)

DATADIR = "../input/histopathologic-cancer-detection/train"
IMG_SIZE = 96
training_data = []
def create_training_data():
    for i in range(0,len(df.index)):
        img_path = df.iloc[i,0]+".tif"
        path = os.path.join(DATADIR, img_path)
        img_array = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        class_num = df.iloc[i,1]
        training_data.append([img_array,class_num])
        print(i)
create_training_data()

print(len(training_data))
random.shuffle(training_data)

X = []
y = []
count = 0

for features, label in training_data:
    X.append(features)
    y.append(label)
    count += 1
    print(count)

X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)

np.save('image_arrays.npy',X)
np.save('labels.npy',y)
```

Code 2:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import shutil

X = np.load("../input/metastasis-cancer-100000/image_arrays.npy", "r")
y = np.load("../input/metastasis-cancer-100000/labels.npy", "r")

X=np.array(X/255.0)
y=np.array(y)
```

UPDATE 1: 
I tried to use `np.memmap()` from a comment suggestion. I'm not very familiar with it, so I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly, but I tried the following code, and the same memory error occured:

```
X = np.memmap("../input/metastasis-cancer-100000/image_arrays.npy", mode="r")
y = np.memmap("../input/metastasis-cancer-100000/labels.npy", mode="r")
```

Comment: Have look at numpy.memmap, might help you to solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Frightera. Unfortunately, It didn't work. I might have implemented it wrong, though.

Comment: X = np.load('../input/metastasis-cancer-100000/image_arrays.npy', mmap_mode='r') that one also worth trying. If this one also fails, I don't have any solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is solved by using:

```
X = np.load('../input/metastasis-cancer-100000/image_arrays.npy', mmap_mode='r')
```

This one nothing but just acts as a normal array, however backed by DISK. Also consider that it will be slower than the arrays which are backed by RAM.